# Script to disable Cloudflare Rocketloader on site

Tags: javascript, cloudflare

I have a site that is under Cloudflare and we've enabled RocketLoader on it.

Now it turned out that at least in Chrome and Firefox it breaks the site - there is some error inside the Cloudflare's script itself and page simply stops loading.

The person who has access to Cloudflare to disable RocketLoader is currently unavailable. Can I do something?

I've tried adding

```
<script>
    window.CloudFlare = [];
</script>
```

as the first script, because CloudFlare's script goes as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{ if (!window.CloudFlare) { ...
//]]>
</script>
```

But it turns out that if my script is inside `<head>...</head>` then Cloudflare's script is always inserted before. I've tried adding it before `<head>` but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try this script to undo RocketLoader damage:

```
undo_rocketloader = function() {
        // If CloudFlare is active attempt to undo the damage to document functions
        if (window.CloudFlare) {
            var i, hp = HTMLDocument.prototype;
            for (i in hp) {
                // Using try to avoid "illegal invocation" errors
                try {
                    // Make sure document functions are same as HTMLDocument.prototype functions
                    if (typeof hp[i] == 'function' && document[i] != hp[i])
                        document[i] = hp[i];
                } catch (e) {}
            }
            // TODO: Retrieve window.getComputedStyle
            // Following method failed because Window.prototype.getComputedStyle is undefined.
            // I couldn't find getComputedStyle in any prototype :(
            // if (window.getComputedStyle != XXX.getComputedStyle)
            //  window.getComputedStyle = XXX.getComputedStyle;             
        } else {
            // If CloudFlare was not loaded yet - this will prevent it from loading
            CloudFlare = {
                define: function() {}
            };
        }
        var damagedScripts = document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/rocketscript"]');
        for (i = 0; i < damagedScripts.length; i++) {
            // If `type` is removed before changing the src, the script would run.
            // We rely on the `data-rocketoptimized` to tell if the script was already called or not (see rocket-loader code near "Scanning for scripts")
            if (damagedScripts[i].getAttribute('data-rocketoptimized') != "true") {
                // script has not run yet? remove type, so that the src change will cause this script to run
                damagedScripts[i].removeAttribute('type'); // 'text/javascript' is default when `type` is removed
            }
            damagedScripts[i].setAttribute('data-rocketoptimized', 'true'); // make sure to never run it again
            if (damagedScripts[i].hasAttribute('data-rocketsrc'))
                damagedScripts[i].setAttribute('src', damagedScripts[i].getAttribute('data-rocketsrc')) // when selecting a script we look for it's src attribute, not data-rocketsrc
            damagedScripts[i].removeAttribute('type'); // 'text/javascript' is default when `type` is removed
        }
    } //undo_rocketloader
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z39sdg73/

Answer (score 1):

Is it only breaking on a certain page? If yes, then you could try disabling Rocket Loader using [PageRules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-) on that page.

Comment: He said that the person with access to CloudFlare is unavailable, so he cannot set page rules as well.